# update-alternatives --install says it needs link name path priority?

Tags: command-line

I typed:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/ jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1
```

It's says alternatives --install needs link name path priority

Comment: What are you typing __exactly__? please be careful with any punctuation (e.g. dashes) and __spaces__

Comment: @steeldriver could you explain link name path priority . If there were no link like "/user/bin/java/" then will erroneous result?

Comment: It should _create_ the link (and the _name_ if there is no current `java` group in `/etc/alternatives`). AFAIK the only thing that must pre-exist is the _path_ component i.e. `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java` - but note that (as posted in your question) you have a space in yours - hence my 1st comment.

Comment: @steeldriver yeah /usr/lib/jvm/bin/java/ is available . I've try sudo update-alternatives -- install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0.05/bin/java" 1

Comment: Are you leaving a space between the `--` and the word `install`? if so, don't - it needs to be `--install`. Also the quotes should not be necessary, just `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0.05/bin/java 1`

Comment: You have a realy problem there, and that is make things complicated, the things are easy to do in the right way, so think simple and don't let it scares you.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Are you leaving a space between the -- and the word install? if so, don't - it needs to be `--install`

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0.05/bin/java 1
```

The quotes should not be necessary since none of the elements have embedded spaces - although they shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that relative paths aren't accepted here, you must use the absolute path.

Comment: what is the range of priority numbers?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

The command sintax is

`sudo update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>`

if there are no space in the parameters, you don't need quotes.

In your case:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java 1`

Pay attention: did you really have a space in the path before jdk?

Comment: What is the difference between <link> and <path>?

Comment: @hafiz031 <path> is the path to executable (for example my java installation), instead <link> is the fake executable, a link that points to the real executable. If you add another jdk, you use the same link (/usr/bin/java) but another jdk. The link is in the $PATH system variable

Answer (score 4):

Just trying to contribute with this post. I use this command, once that I know my setup correctly.

```
echo 1 | sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 3):

This is beacause this command maintains symbolic links. I recommend to execute `man update-alternatives` to get more information about the command.